# Python projects are not supported on Windows Function Apps. Deploy to a Linux Function App instead

Tags: azure-functions

I have tried to deploy my first Azure Function from VS Code, Python. Windows 10.

Although everything else is okay, VS Code says that it is impossible to do it from Windows OS.

Is there absolutely no way of doing that via Windows?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by impossible? State your error correctly in the question to provide fix for that!

Comment: Show us the error with a screen shot .. show us the code you say runs fine ..

Comment: I have added screenshot, please see in description

Comment: The Error in your screenshot clearly saying that you have to deploy your python function project to the Linux Function App instead of windows! And check the list of supported environments and versions given by @Suryasrikamini-MT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is Creating the Function App on VS Code in the Windows OS environment and publishing it to Linux Function App in Azure.

As of now, Python Azure Functions are not supported in Windows Azure Function App.

Refer the [supporting operating System/Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#operating-systemruntime) of Azure Python Functions for more information.

As per this [MSFT reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Cazurecli-linux%2Capplication-level),

> Although you can develop your Python-based functions locally on Windows, Python functions are supported in Azure only when they're running on Linux.